# R Shiny: error when interactive input goes into a ggplot from rds file (Error in eval: object 'x' not found)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, save

I want to produce an application using R's `shiny` package. I would like to upload ggplots from another project and add some interactive content.

When I add a data point using `geom_point()` to a ggplot that was created in the same R code this works fine. However, when I save and re-read the ggplot again (*), an error occurs. I could still add the `geom_point` (**), but it does not accept the interactive content from `input$slider`.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(

  fluidPage(

    # Title
    titlePanel(""),

    # sidebar
    sidebarLayout(

      sidebarPanel("",
                   sliderInput("slider", "slider",
                               min = 100, max = 500, value = 300, step = 10)
      ),

      # Main
      mainPanel("",

                plotOutput("ggplt")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(

  function(input, output){

    # produce a plot
    output$ggplt <- renderPlot({

      # ggplot scatterplot
      library(ggplot2)
      gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
        geom_point()

      # (*) save ggplot
      #saveRDS(gg, "plt.rds")
      #rm(gg)
      #gg <- readRDS("plt.rds")

      # x-coordinate for geom_point 
      xc <- as.numeric(input$slider)

      gg + geom_point(aes(x = xc, y = 20), size = 5, colour = "red")

      ## (**) alternative
      #gg + geom_point(aes(x = 400, y = 20), size = 5, colour = "red")
    }) 

  }
)
```

Comment: see http://tagteam.harvard.edu/hub_feeds/1981/feed_items/2104863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what is going on here, and I think it is probably some subtle interaction between the ggplot2 environment handling and the shiny reactive environment handling. It might be worth flagging as a bug.

However there are a number of ways to make it work with small changes. I think the best is to use a reactive function for the slider value, although just assigning `xc` with the frowned upon `<<-` also seems to work and is a smaller change.

You could also just use `input$slider` directly in the `aes(..)` function as that seems to work too, but using a reactive function feels cleaner.

So this is what I suggest as a workaround:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
u <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("", sliderInput("slider", "slider",
                       min = 100, max = 500, value = 300, step = 10)
      ),
      mainPanel("", plotOutput("ggplt")
      )
)))
s <- shinyServer(  function(input, output){

    sliderval <- reactive({input$slider})

    output$ggplt <- renderPlot({
      req(input$slider)

      gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
        geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg))

      # (*) save ggplot
      saveRDS(gg, "plt.rds")
      rm(gg)
      gg <- readRDS("plt.rds")

      gg + geom_point(aes(x = sliderval(), y = 20), size = 5, colour = "red")
    }) 
})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

yielding:

[image]